# OOP Python составить список студентов

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Я написала класс `Student`, но не получается сделать вот это:

Составьте список студентов. Позвольте пользователю добавлять студентов в
список. Спрашивайте имя студента и выводите его / ее данные.

По каждому учебному курсу укажите нагрузки в часах. создайте
метод `creditHours`, что вычисляет общую нагрузку студента в семестре.
Сообщите о превышении нагрузки, если оно больше `limitHours`.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name="John Doe", courses=[], phone="1", email="@"):
        self.name = name
        self.courses = courses
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        print("Створено об’єкт для " + name)

    def printDetails(self):
        print("Ім’я: ", self.name)
        print("Курси: ", self.courses)
        print("Номер телефону: ", self.phone)
        print("Поштова адреса: ", self.email)

    def enroll(self, course):
        self.courses.append(course)


student1 = Student("Mary", ["L548"], "066", "Mary@gmail.com")

print("Уведіть курси, які вивчає ", student1.name)
newcourse = input("Уведіть номер курсу або 'stop' ")
while newcourse != "stop":
    student1.enroll(newcourse)
    print("Уведіть курси, які вивчає", student1.name)
    newcourse = input("Уведіть номер курсу або 'stop' ")
student1.printDetails()
```

Comment: с курсами - недоработочка. по каждому курсу надо вводить и количиство часов, на протяжении которых читается курс. Так что для каждого курса - два значения, название и количество часов...

Comment: Можете помочь, пожалуйста, а то уже 3 часа просидела над этими заданиями и все равно не понимаю как сделать

Comment: вчитайтесь в условие. у вас все получится.  список лекций - самостоятельная сущность...